# How can I make API calls with a progress bar and a return function while being efficient on Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm making an app based on a lot of data I get from an API. I need this information before showing the actual app so I put the code that takes care of fetching these information on a loading screen. I save all of it on a local database (Room Database) so I don't have to fetch it everytime I launch the app (since the API doesn't change much) and so I can actually use the info.

**1st problem :** When I try my code it saves objects twice (or more) (probably because of Coroutines). And since I base wether the fetch ended on how *many saves happened* / *number of results*, this leads to the activity thinking the fetch has finished, stopping all calls. Meaning some objects don't have time to be saved.

Here's my code (simplified) :

```
class FetchFromAPI {
    fun fetchObjects(save: (Object) -> Unit) {
        //Get number objects from API call
        val count = API.getCount()

        //Calculate number of pages
        val limit = 100
        var pageCount = count / limit
        if (count % limit != 0) pageCount++

        //For each page
        for (i in 1..pageCount) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                //Get page
                val page = API.getPage(i)
                //Save objects from page
                savePage(page, save)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun savePage(
        page: JSONArray,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //For each object in page
        for (i in 0..page.length()) {
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                //Get object
                val obj = page.getJSONObject(i)
                //Save object
                saveObject(obj, save)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveObject(
        obj: JSONObject,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //Convert Json to Object
        ...

        save(obj)
    }
}
```

`saveObject(obj)` is a function that saves the object on Room Database and update the progress of the fetch (controlled by Flows).

So I googled and found out about `join()` on jobs and `runBlocking{}` and I thought "I don't need an exact number for the progress since it is showed with a ProgressBar and I'm dealing with a couple thousands objects, so if I can know when all my Coroutines are finished and base the return call off of this instead of the progress, I'm good (even if the multiple calls are wasting some resources)".

**2nd problem :** When I tried using `runBlocking{}` **or** `join()`, so I could start a function saying it's finished, the function either gets me an "App is frozen" error or just doesn't start at all.

My code changed (simplified) :

```
class FetchFromAPI {
    fun fetchObjects(save: (Object) -> Unit) {
        //Get number objects from API call
        val count = API.getCount()

        //Calculate number of pages
        val limit = 100
        var pageCount = count / limit
        if (count % limit != 0) pageCount++

        runBlocking {
            //For each page
            for (i in 1..pageCount) {
                launch {
                    //Get page
                    val page = API.getPage(i)
                    //Save objects from page
                    savePage(page, save)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun savePage(
        page: JSONArray,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //For each object in page
        runBlocking {
            for (i in 0..page.length()) {
                launch {
                    //Get object
                    val obj = page.getJSONObject(i)
                    //Save object
                    saveObject(obj, save)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun saveObject(
        obj: JSONObject,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //Convert Json to Object
        ...

        save(obj)
    }
}

fun fetchingFromAPI(onFinished: () -> Unit) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        fetchObjects(::save)
        onFinished()
    }
}
```

Is there something I don't understand about Coroutines, `join()` and `runBlocking{}` ?

Tell me if you need anything else from my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

runBlocking blocks the thread that you calling it until finish it's execution.
Probably that the reason of the frozen error, because you block the IO thread in a for loop and you call the save callback from there.
I would suggest you to make all functions suspend to be able to use join without the runBlocking. When a function is suspend it can suspend it's execution and is possible to join other coroutines.

```
    class FetchFromAPI {
    suspend fun fetchObjects(save: (Object) -> Unit) {
        //Get number objects from API call
        val count = API.getCount()

        //Calculate number of pages
        val limit = 100
        var pageCount = count / limit
        if (count % limit != 0) pageCount++

        //Create a list of coroutines and join them all, so the fetchObjects 
        //will return after all the pages are saved
        (1..pageCount).map { i ->
            launch {
                //Get page
                val page = API.getPage(i)
                //Save objects from page
                savePage(page, save)
            }
        }.joinAll()
    }

    private suspend fun savePage(
        page: JSONArray,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //Same logic here
        (0..page.length()).map { i ->
            launch {
                //Get object
                val obj = page.getJSONObject(i)
                //Save object
                saveObject(obj, save)
            }
        }.joinAll()
    }

    //Here if the save(obj) does not generates any new coroutine you do not need to 
    //use suspend other wise you have to use suspend and make also the save fun 
    //suspend and join the coroutine inside it.
    private fun saveObject(
        obj: JSONObject,
        save: (Object) -> Unit
    ) {
        //Convert Json to Object
        ...

        save(obj)
    }
}
```

Now you can call the fetchObjects from a coroutine like you did in the second part of code like this:

```
    fun fetchingFromAPI(onFinished: () -> Unit) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            fetchObjects(::save)
            onFinished()
        }
    }
```

Probably this needs a little debugging but because I do not have the rest  of your code I cannot do it, so please let me know if there is any error or if is not working like you expected.

Example of switching thread inside a coroutine:

```
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            //What ever is inside the fetchObjects will run on the IO thread
            fetchObjects(::save)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                //Whatever is inside the onFinished will run on the main thread
                onFinished()
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's working ! Thank you so much !
And I found where my the first problem came from : In my coroutines I was using a var declared outside (so they all used the same var)
But when I put some logs i noticed the pages where dealt with 1 by 1 (not in order though) instead of being lauched in parallel :/
I launch all my Coroutiones through Dispatchers.IO, I thought it was to create a background thread, is it the same thread each time ?

Comment: Hmm it should be run in parallel, but I cannot debug it from my system because I do not have all of the code.
From the documentation:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine
A coroutine is an instance of a suspendable computation. It is conceptually similar to a thread, in the sense that it takes a block of code to run that works concurrently with the rest of the code. However, a coroutine is not bound to any particular thread. It may suspend its execution in one thread and resume in another one.
So the way you call it it runs on the IO thread in each loop.

Comment: So as the documentation says you can switch threads inside a coroutine.
I will edit my answer and put an example there.

Comment: Is there any runBlocking call inside the save function or anywhere else?
Because if you say the the pages are not dealt in order means that the code that we see in this post is trying to run in paraller.

Comment: An other reason that maybe the pages are dealt one by one is if the library you are using for the API calls does not allows you to have more than one requests active.

Comment: I don't have any runBlocking in my code anymore. I put some more Logs in my code, turns out, all the pages' coroutines start at the same time. But as you said, each api call to a page is done 1 by 1. What's weird is that when I get the response, it should immediately start the next one instead of waiting for objects from the page to be saved. But it might just be that the request is longer than converting and saving all the objects from the page idk (I'm using OkHttp for my API calls)

Comment: I was using the same OkHttpClient object to make all my calls, I tried creating a new one for each call and it's a bit better

Comment: You can also define a dispatcher and set the max number of requests per host,  the default value is 5, and the default value in general is 64. I thing is not good practice to create a new client for each request.  Here is a code snippet to do that: `val dispatcher =  Dispatcher()
dispatcher.setMaxRequests(set max here)
dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(set max per host here)
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .dispatcher(dispatcher)
    .build();`